# can we customize files. Upload() in google colab?

Tags: python, file-upload, browser, google-colaboratory, visualization

I have tried several ways ,but not able to resolve the problem .can we customize browsing functionality in colab?

[image]

I am using uploaded = files.upload() for browse button functionality in colab, but I want whenever user click browse direct dialogue box for given path should open rather than choose files option.

Answer (score 0):

The situation that you discuss is possible if you build your own customized application. But google collab is a proprietary application of google and it has a certain set of operations to do tasks smoothly. Apart from that as you say

"user click browse direct dialogue box for given path should open rather than choose files option"

how it is possible that google colab now what you want to upload. That's why google colab gives you the facility to upload the file as per your requirement. It makes the application more robust and easy to use.

As per Google colab documentation, it is not possible.